# In a procedure connect to 2 databases: one local and the other remote

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, database-connection, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to write a stored procedure, in DB2 for AS400, which runs a query on the local database (the same where the procedure is stored; it's named `DBLocale`) and an other on a remote database (let's call it `DBRemoto`). In iSeries Navigator I can see both of them selecting "Database" node.

I tried something with `CONNECT TO DBRemoto;` and/or `SET CONNECTION DBRemoto;`, but got weird results: "connection already exists", "connection doesn't exist", "CALL instruction completed" (but no result set) etc. .

This would be what I expect to do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.TEST_CONNECT_INSIDE_PROCEDURE
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
LANGUAGE SQL 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE sql_string VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE locale INT DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE remoto INT DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR stmt;
    DECLARE curOut CURSOR FOR select locale, remoto from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

    -- run the same query in both DBs; I checked, results must be different
    SET sql_string = 'select count(*) as QTY from MYLIB.MYTABLE';

    -- run locally
    CONNECT TO DBLocale; --it's one of my attempts
    PREPARE stmt FROM sql_string;
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO locale;
    CLOSE cur;

    -- run remotely
    CONNECT TO DBRemoto; --it's one of my attempts
    PREPARE stmt FROM sql_string;
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO remoto;
    CLOSE cur;

    -- output results
    OPEN curOut;
    SET RESULT SETS CURSOR curOut;
END;
```

I call it with

```
call MYLIB.TEST_CONNECT_INSIDE_PROCEDURE()
```

Can someone tell me if it is possible and clarify how it works, please? If it's not possible in a procedure, is there a workaround? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On IBM i, you need to include both the user and password parameters for remote databases.

```
CONNECT TO DBRemoto USER QUAGMEIER USING 'GIGIDY'
```

The password needs to be in upper case and at least in embedded RPG it needs to be in a host variable.

Comment: Bob Cozzi and a Family Guy reference.  Awesome.

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that password needs quotes? Anyway it doesn't work in any case: it doesn't create the procedure and gives me a SQL7032 error.

Answer (score 1):

Under IBM i 7.1, Technical Refresh 4 allows connection to multiple databases and 3-part naming.  This means a table (or view) reference can take the form *dbname.schema.table*, as long as *dbname* is an entry in the Relational Database Directory.